# Develop Apache Kafka producer and load testing using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, apache-kafka

Is it possible to use JMeter to push messages to Apache Kafka.

How to implement producer (in JAVA) to push messages to Kafka.

Regards,
Anand

Comment: For a non-JMeter option, see: https://github.com/mnogu/gatling-kafka

Answer (score 4):

I thought there was an answer earlier, maybe not. Have you taken a look at these? I'm using the original kafkameter myself.

- https://github.com/BrightTag/kafkameter
- https://github.com/EugeneYushin/new-api-kafkameter

and tutorials on kafkameter:

- http://www.technix.in/load-testing-apache-kafka-using-kafkameter
- http://codyaray.com/2014/07/custom-jmeter-samplers-and-config-elements

For use outside of JMeter, I've found it easier to write a producer load tool in say ruby, python, or node.js than in Java. But it's personal preference. Load scalability is another matter but other languages are easier to prototype out a producer tool.

**Update:**

Since the original post, there's now another solution/option for JMeter:

- https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box

and rather than post specific tutorials about it, you're better off googling for some mix of terms like "Pepper-Box kafka jmeter" and go over the tutorial results for those as there are quite a few. The ones from BlazeMeter should be good.

Comment: It might be usefull https://dzone.com/articles/apache-kafka-load-testing-using-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can go with the `Jmeter` by using the above external libraries given by @David, above. Just to add, I'd recommend you to have two different programs for both consumer and producer so that you'll be in more control on what's going on. Such as optimizing and changing the property files within the config according to your requirements. Even though `JMeter` sounds easy on `loadtesting`, I'm not sure whether you'll be able to identify the efficiency of message consumption or production, such as identifying the number of messages published or consumed within a certain amount of period (ie: if you're dealing with large number of messages).

Kafka Produce Sample given in the [doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example) and [this](https://github.com/bkimminich/apache-kafka-book-examples/blob/master/src/test/kafka/SimpleProducer.java)

Comment: Good points. The kafkameter plugin doesn't offer validation of produced messages as well, so one has to validate externally or modify the plugin. JMeter will only report the send rate from kafkameter, but that might not equate to the received and processed rate on kafka server side. And then there's the separate consuming of the loaded messages.